# CSS3 slide up effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just wondering how can I replicate this effect from this [website](http://2.0.gamingforschools.info/), with the slightly overlapping description box that slides up on hover. Is there a way to do it in either CSS3 or Jquery? I have tried using the same code from the example site but it has the bars either site of the image which I can't seem to remove.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.description {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  background: orange;
}

.container:hover .description {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="description">
   <p>Hover for more info.</p>
   <p>Hello there.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. How can I make the slide up bar slightly overlap with information in it?  thanks

Comment: Here is a jquery verison of it with `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`
http://jsfiddle.net/wx4n07uv/

Comment: @user2835935 to show say, half the info, then set the bottom property to a smaller number. see updated example

Comment: @user2835935 to help others, mark the answer that answered your question as accepted :)